# Select2 - Resubmit form on select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use Select2 plugin to display a searchable dropdown (with option to select multiple items). Can someone help me to get the form (re)submitted every time a new value is selected (and deselected, if possible).

I know select2 has "select" event, but I can't get the code working. Form code:

```
<select class="form-control select2-search" name="product_id[]" multiple="multiple"><option value='1'>1</option>...<option value='999'>999</option></select>
```

Here's the code for Select2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $eventSelect=$(".select2-search").select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: 6
});
$eventSelect.on("select2:select", function() {
this.submit();
});
});
</script>
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are actually submiting the select, not the form..

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $eventSelect=$(".select2-search").select2({
       minimumResultsForSearch: 6
    });
    $eventSelect.on("select2:select", function() {
       console.log("select2:select");
       $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Or try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $eventSelect=$(".select2-search").select2({
           minimumResultsForSearch: 6
        });
        $eventSelect.on("change", function() {
           console.log("select2:select");
           $(this).parents('form').find('button').click();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but it still doesn't work (I need to click the Submit button manually to get the form working)

Comment: check my edits, and please let me know if the console.log happens

Comment: It does "something" now. When I select any item, the page quickly reloads (the item remains checked), but the form still doesn't get submitted. That's all so far. See it here - http://lipskas.com/bandymas/index.php

Comment: I used Firefox LiveHeaders plugin, and I see that form actually GETS SUBMITTED. The reason why I though it didn't work - auto submit didn't submit the value of submit button itself (<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_ok">). If it's not possible to also auto submit the value of this button, I'll modify some code in the form, no problems

Comment: It really did! Thank you very much for your help, I don't have much experience in javascript. Thanks again and have a nice weekend